# Error message: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (65536,) (2,)

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm trying to remove outliers from a dataframe:

```
df.shape
(65536, 3)
```

To do so, I created a function, where Tag is the label of the columns:

```
def outliers(dataset, Tag):
  Q1 = dataset[Tag].quantile(0.25)
  Q3 = dataset[Tag].quantile(0.75)
  IQR = Q3 -Q1
  Lsup = Q3 + 1,5*IQR
  Linf = Q1 - 1,5*IQR

  list = dataset.index[(dataset[Tag] > upper_bound) or (dataset[Tag] < lower_bound)]

  return list
```

Then I created an empty list to store the output indices from the multiple columns:

```
index_list = []
for columns in ['L4553', 'F5432']:
  index_list.extend(outliers(df, columns))
```

After this, the error appears:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (65536,) (2,)
```

Could you guys help me, please? I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does that error appear out of no where?  without any context or traceback?  You need to identify which operation has this problem, and examine the relevant variables.  You can't do things like `+` or `<` on arrays with different shapes like that.

Answer (score 1):

This code needs 3 fixes to work:

1. You don't set the variables `upper_bound` or `lower_bound` inside the function, so I'm assuming these are actually supposed to be `Lsup` and `Linf`.
2. I'm assuming you meant to use decimals instead of commas when setting `Lsup` and `Linf`. This should dix the error you were getting (since using a comma makes them tuples).
3. You'll find you get another error though, which can be fixed by using `np.logical_or()` when checking for values that fall outside of the upper or lower bound.

With these changes your codes should look like the following:

```
import numpy as np

def outliers(dataset, Tag):
    Q1 = dataset[Tag].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = dataset[Tag].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 -Q1
    Lsup = Q3 + 1.5*IQR
    Linf = Q1 - 1.5*IQR

    list = dataset.index[np.logical_or(dataset[Tag] > Lsup, dataset[Tag] < Linf)]

    return list
```